# How to reverse to the previous branch in SWIFT?

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-commit

I merged my newest xcode commit with older ones i.e. I pressed "Checkout" but now it looks like I am unable to recover the newest build as my main build is the older one I merged.

Is there any way to go back to the newest build I just merged with the older one?

[attaching an image of my commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVdHc.jpg)

Comment: question isn't clear can you please elaborate

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift or Xcode, just a plain git question, so removed unrelated tags.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I wanted to go back to my previous commit in Xcode and to do that I pressed checkout on an older brach committed a few days ago. Now, my main project became the older branch, and all the "newer" commits (created after the older branch) disappeared. Is there any way to recover them?

Comment: you can cherry pick those commits, for this install fork login with your account select project you can see all of commits, now check out your desired branch and pick one by one commits to add in specific to your branch